EDITED: Recipient not receiving message after registering with WeakReferenceMessenger
I'm using MVVM from community toolkit WeakReferenceMessenger to send messages and data between my ViewModels. I have a client-server model and I'm experiencing problems on my client.
I have one listening thread that listens the incoming messages from the server. When a session started then message is received a StartSessionMessage (derived from RequestMessage<Session>) is send WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new StartSessionMessage(MapSession(sessionData))).
Currently there are 4 receiving ViewModels all subscribing to this message in the same way
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StartSessionMessage>(this, (r, m) => { InitSession(m.Session); });

Message:
public class StartSessionMessage : RequestMessage<Session>
{
    public Session Session { get; set; }

    public StartSessionMessage(Session session)
    {
        Session = session;
    }
}

Sender:
        public async Task StartServerAsync()
        {
            string clientIP = NetworkManager.GetLocalIpv4();
            int clientPort = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("LocalPort"));
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(clientIP);
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, clientPort);

            using Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
            var buffer = new byte[128_000_000];

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // Receive message
                    var handler = listener.Accept();
                    int received = handler.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                    var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

                    if (receivedMessage.Contains(MessageTags.SESSION))
                    {
                        receivedMessage = receivedMessage.Replace(MessageTags.SESSION, "");
                        var sessionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionData>(receivedMessage);
                        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new StartSessionMessage(MapSession(sessionData)));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                listener.Close();
                Task.Run(() => { _ = StartServerAsync(); });
            }
        }

Receiver 1:
public MainWindowViewModel(Window window)
{
    _window = window;
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StartSessionMessage>(this, (r, m) => { InitSession(m.Session); });

    var baseGameView = new BaseGameView();
    baseGameView.Show();

    var gameScoreView = new GameScoresView();
    gameScoreView.Show();
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToBigScreen(gameScoreView, false, WindowState.Minimized, WindowStyle.None);

    var editPlayersView = new EditPlayersView();
    editPlayersView.Show();

    var ImageScreenView = new ImageScreenView();
    ImageScreenView.Show();
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToBigScreen(ImageScreenView, false, WindowState.Maximized, WindowStyle.None);
}

private void InitSession(Session messageValue)
{
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToSmallScreen(_window, false, WindowState.Minimized, WindowStyle.None);
}

Receiver 2:
public BaseGameViewModel(Window window)
{
    _window = window;
    Session = new Session();

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StartSessionMessage>(this, (r, m) => { InitSession(m.Session); });
}

private void InitSession(Session session)
{
    Session = session;
    Session.WarmUpDoneEvent += ChangeTimeText;
    Session.SessionDoneEvent += SessionDone;
    Session.SessionStoppedEvent += StopSession;
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToSmallScreen(_window, false, WindowState.Minimized, WindowStyle.None);
}

Receiver 3:
public GameScoresViewModel(Window window)
{
    _window = window;

    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StartSessionMessage>(this, (r, m) => { InitSession(m.Session); });
}

private void InitSession(Session session)
{
    TeamName = session.TeamName;
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToBigScreen(_window, true, WindowState.Maximized, WindowStyle.None);
}

Receiver 4:
public EditPlayersViewModel(Window window)
{
    _window = window;
    _isListReset = true;
    _resetSelectedIndex = false;
    _firstTime = true;
    _players = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<StartSessionMessage>(this, (r, m) => { InitSession(m.Session); });
}

private void InitSession(Session session)
{
    Players = new ObservableCollection<Player>(session.Players.Select(x => new Player(x)));
    _isListReset = true;
    _firstTime = true;
    WindowManipulator.SetWindowToSmallScreen(_window, true, WindowState.Maximized, WindowStyle.None);
}

For some reason I have one ViewModel, Receiver 4, that does not receive the message, EditPlayers, and it is always this one that doesn't execute the InitSession code. The views are always loaded in the same order, they are fully separate windows all started from the MainWindow code-behind.
So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong, is there a max amount of registers for 1 message?

Tried searching online for maximums or other cases with the same issue but found nothing.
Tried to change the message from RequestMessage<Session> to ValueChangedMessage<Session>, also didn't change anything. Thought maybe the type of message had a limit of recipients.
Doubled checked the code and if the correct message was being used across the registers.


I found the solution myself. It turns out one of recipient 3 that received the message before recipient 4 had an error while executing its code in the WindowManipulator.SetWindowToBigScreen (self-written code). It did not show on screen until now, it was a random test.
Conclusion check for errors in the recipients that receive the message before the receiver in question. The reference manager stops after an error and executes each register sequential.
